# Download images from Mechanical Turk

Tags: python, mechanicalturk

I have a bunch of urls in Mechanical Turk where I can download the uploaded images from.  I wrote a Python script to download all the files.  However, I have to be logged in to Mechanical Turk to access the files first.  Is there an API or best practice for downloading a large number of files from Mechanical Turk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boto http://boto.cloudhackers.com/ is a Python wrapper for Amazon Web Services, including Mechanical Turk; see the Mechanical Turk API reference at http://boto.cloudhackers.com/ref/mturk.html

Alternatively you could use urllib2, mechanize, or Scrapy to grab them directly. All three will support either basic authentication or cookie-based form authentication.